# Select value of input boxes created with jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

So I have this jquery:

```
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });


var $content = "";
$('#tags').keyup(function() {    
     $content =  $('input').attr('value'); 
     $content2 =$('.ui-widget').parent().html();
     $("#placehere").append($content2)

});


$('.ui-widget').parent().css('color', 'red');
```

And this HTML:

```
<div class="demo">
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
    <div id="placehere">Click</div>
</div>
```

I would like the results which are appended to the `#placehere` div to be ONLY the text inside of the input boxes that are generated by the autocomplete form.

Currently, It just copies the HTML of everything `.parent()` to the `.ui-widget` div.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty in figuring out what exactly you're trying to do - do you want the selected item text to appear inside the `#placehere` div when you select an item?  Also, do you really want to use the `keyup` function?  That's going to fire every time you press a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to pull back the active autocomplete list using the keyup event because the ui-autocomplete div has not been created yet. You can verify by putting a break point in your keyup event. You can get around that by creating a timeout or using an animated delay with callback.

Comment: ok thank you. I was just trying to do something that was redundant